# Matlab: Convert cell string (comma separated) to vector

Tags: string, matlab, vector, double, type-conversion

I have a huge csv file (as in: more than a few gigs) and would like to read it in Matlab and process each file. Reading the file in its entirety is impossible so I use this code to read in each line:

```
fileName = 'input.txt';
inputfile = fopen(fileName);

while 1
    tline = fgetl(inputfile);
    if ~ischar(tline)
        break
    end
end
fclose(inputfile);
```

This yiels a cell array of size(1,1) with the line as string. What I would like is to convert this cell to a normal array with just the numbers.
For example:

```
input.csv:
0.0,0.0,3.201,0.192
2.0,3.56,0.0,1.192
0.223,0.13,3.201,4.018
```

End result in Matlab for the first line:

```
A = [0.0,0.0,3.201,0.192]
```

I tried converting tline with double(tline) but this yields completely different results. Also tried using a regex but got stuck there. I got to the point where I split up all values into a different cell in one array. But converting to double with str2double yields only NaNs...

Any tips? Preferably without any loops since it already takes a while to read the entire file.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a the `row`, `col`, and `range` arguments to CSV read?

Comment: Use `str2num(tline)` instead of `str2double`.

Comment: There is good advice on handling large datasets in MATLAB in this file exchange item. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9060

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `str2num`

```
>> A = '0.0,0.0,3.201,0.192';
>> str2num(A)
ans =
     0  0  3.2010  0.1920
>> A = '0.0 0.0 3.201 0.192';
>> str2num(A)
ans =
     0  0  3.2010  0.1920
>> A = '0.0     0.0 ,    3.201 , 0.192';
>> str2num(A)
ans =
     0  0  3.2010  0.1920
```

e.g., it's quite agnostic to input format.

However, I will not advise this for your use case. For your problem, I'd do

```
C = dlmread('input.txt',',', [1 1 1 inf]) % for first line
C = dlmread('input.txt',',')              % for entire file
```

or

```
[a,b,c,d] = textread('input.txt','%f,%f,%f,%f',1) % for first line
[a,b,c,d] = textread('input.txt','%f,%f,%f,%f')   % for entire file
```

if you want all columns in separate variables:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 3.201
d = 0.192
```

or

```
fid = fopen('input.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 1); % for first line only
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', N); % for first N lines
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 1, 'headerlines', N-1); % for Nth line only
fclose(fid);
```

all of which are much more easily expandable (things like this, whatever they are, tend to grow bigger over time :). Especially `dlmread` is much less prone to errors than writing your own clauses is, for empty lines, missing values and other great nuisances very common in most data sets.

Comment: This seems like the perfect answer to my problem, however, I can't get the 'inf' parameter to work... It gives an error:
Non-finite endpoints or increment for colon operator in index

Comment: @Tim: woops, seems I didn't test thoroughly enough. I don't have the opportunity right now, but can you try `C = dlmread('input.txt',',', 1)`? (i.e., without the vector), or `C = dlmread('input.txt',',', 1:10)` (for first 10 lines, hopefully :)

Comment: I tried both but both don't work. I fixed it by manually specifying the columnrange since I know this from another matrix (even though this of course is not very modular).
Also I can read through the file by try-catching every line to catch the end of the file (since I don't know the row-range).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data = dlmread('input.txt',',')
```

It will do exactly what you want to do.

If you still want to convert string to a vector:

```
line_data = sscanf(line,'%g,',inf)
```

This code will read the entire coma-separated string and convert each number.